# Как извлекать информацию из файла в код?

Tags: c++

у меня есть файл, предположим `file.txt` в нем текст

```
Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
```

и есть код, который принимает данные и кодирует символы в трехзначные номера.

сейчас я кодирую их из переменной `string txt` потому что у меня нету реализации переноса данных с файла в цикл.

```
string txt = "Hello world";


пока не понял как это работает
int code[] = { 0, ...., 151, 113, .... };


for (auto a : txt) {
    auto i = coder.at(string(1, a));

    cout << i << " result " << endl;
}
```

Мне надо что бы данные шли из файла, так же мне интересно будет ли работать если файл будет очень большой, например 1 гигобайт данных в тексте.

возможно стоит как то по другому кодировать данные. Сейчас я точно не уверен, правильно ли я делаю, или нет.

Comment: fopen() из libc используй для открытия файла (чтения, записи, добавления...). На счёт большого файла, загружай файл в буфер частями, обрабатывай, сохраняй в другой файл, загружай следующую порцию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, через `map` - издевательство из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно". Проще массив перекодировки, где символы - их стандартные ASCII-коды - служат индексами, а ваши числа - значениями - типа

```
int code[] = { 0, ...., 151, 113, .... };
```

где 151 находится в элементе номер 100 (=`d`), 113 - в элементе номер 101 (=`e`) и так далее.

Далее - все, просто читайте файл (или строку) по символу, но вместо символа `c` выводите число `code[c]`.

Идея понятна?

P.S. Правда, не понимаю, что вы хотите получить... простенькое шифрование?

P.P.S. С чтением из файла

```
ifstream in("file.txt",ios::binary);
for(char c; in.get(c); cout << code[c]);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102336/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-------).